# Redirect an archive page to its relevant URL-friendly filtered page

Tags: filters, redirect

I have URL-friendly filtering plugin enabled (WP Grid Builder) and I want to utilise this for the category archive page.

I want to redirect an archive page `https://tag.alfian.co/blog/category/branding/` to `https://tag.alfian.co/blog/?_tag_thoughts=branding` with `tag_thoughts` being the Facet's name and `=branding` being the category. Note: those are real working URLs.

I don't mind using a redirection plugin or even a custom PHP redirection code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The plugin Redirection is good for this kind of thing if you don't want to use code. https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Answer (score 0):

Welcome aboard,

This should be made with the PHP rewrite rule in WordPress functions, but if you don't want to use PHP, you can use the `.htaccess` redirection.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.*)$ /blog/?_tag_thoughts=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Change WordPress .htaccess code with code below

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^blog/category/(.*)$ /blog/?_tag_thoughts=$1 [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```